# Python: repeat sequence in function call

Tags: python-3.x

I'm sorry if the naming of this question isn't good or correct

I don't know if this is even possible, or if there is an easy way to do this

`function(` > `x[0] * y[0] +` < repeat this sequence for the length of x  `z)`

Comment: Hello there, understand your question is answered. I suggest that for your next post, to use proper [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) especially when you are posting some code in your question. This is  to help readers visualize better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List comprehension may be what you're looking for. Use `zip` to merge the lists.

```
xlst = [1,2,3,4,5]
ylst = [5,4,3,2,1]

total = sum([x*y for x,y in zip(xlst,ylst)])  # 35
```

Comment: I didnt understand the question. Looks like you understood and wrote the code for it. +1 for it.

Comment: i was wondering if i could do something similar to this
    `sum([x * y for x, y in zip(xlst, ylst[i]) for i in ylst])`

Comment: If each element in ylst is a list, you can use `.....for i in len(ylst)])`